# How to get from multiple tables using EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

For example I have these three tables . The second 2 tables have firstID as its foreign key. However I did not explicitely set this relation using entity framework and thought I'll handle it in the BLL. Is there a simple way I can get all the data from all 3 tables using the firstID ? . I know i can join using sql query but thinking of a easier approach. 
Note: the Second and third table can have many records with the same FirstId. So I am using a list to construct my FirstTable object

```
FirstTable
public int firstID {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
public List<SecondTable> second {get; set;}
public List<ThirdTable> third {get; set;}

SecondTable
public int secondID {get;set;}
public int number {get;set;}
public int firstID {get;set;}

ThirdTable
public int thirdID {get;set;}
public int age {get;set;}
public int firstID {get;set;}
```

Comment: why don't you setup relations in EF? any reason or any difficulties?

Comment: are you using code first approach or database first approach? You manually define relation between tables and again bind you model from database.You will get all three tables data in single object

Comment: Code first approach